# order of list as feature in nltk: Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp

How can I use the **order** of a list as feature for a Naive Bayes Classifier in nltk in python. I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/noahchalifour/Desktop/paper-writing-tool/sent_analysis.py", line 57, in <module>
    classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/classify/naivebayes.py", line 198, in train
    feature_freqdist[label, fname][fval] += 1
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

This is the code:

```
import nltk

data = [("Hello how are you", 1),
        ("How is your day going", 1),
        ("This is very cool", 0),
        ("Machine learning is awesome", 0)]

def get_features(text):
    return {'order': text.split(' ')}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_data = [(get_features(text), cls) for text, cls in data]
    classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_data)
```

I want to be able to classify text based on the order of the words. For example:

```
"Hello, how are you today?" --> ["Hello", "how", "are", "you", "today", "?"] --> 1  
"This is awesome!" --> ["This", "is", "awesome", "!"] --> 0
```

Comment: please post full stacktrace and a reproduceable example ([mcve])

Comment: is this better? @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: can't make it work. BayesClassifier seems to require one more `feature_probdist` parameter.

Comment: sorry forgot to add something @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: there @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: as said in the error message, `list` type isn't hashable, but `tuple` is.

I would replace your `get_features()` code by:

    def get_features(text):
        return {'order': tuple(text.split(' '))}

so the values are of type `tuple`, which is hashable. But I don't know if it's going to do any good.